# My git push to GitHub via SSH is coming from another user

Tags: git, github

How is it possible that the git push via SSH from my local machine looks like coming from another user? When I look into my GitHub repo I see that my push comes from a unknown account.

Comment: look at your local `git config -l`, fields `user.name` and `user.email`

Comment: if you're ssh'd into another machine why would you expect it to post as the user on your machine?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! The user.name and the user.email were not set in my local .git/config file. After adding the correct values, it worked correct.